Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in php file
I transfered a beta wordpress site from one hosting company to another using a plugin.. and now I am getting this in the header:
http://www.lrcsocal.org

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /webroot/l/r/lrcso001/primary/www/wp-includes/media.php on line 467


Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /webroot/l/r/lrcso001/primary/www/wp-includes/media.php on line 477

When I look at those lines it's:

Here are lines 450-487 if that helps? I know nothing about php! Thank you!!!
    if ( IMAGETYPE_GIF == $orig_type ) {
        if ( !imagegif( $newimage, $destfilename ) )
            return new WP_Error('resize_path_invalid', __( 'Resize path invalid' ));
    } elseif ( IMAGETYPE_PNG == $orig_type ) {
        if ( !imagepng( $newimage, $destfilename ) )
            return new WP_Error('resize_path_invalid', __( 'Resize path invalid' ));
    } else {
        // all other formats are converted to jpg
        $destfilename = "{$dir}/{$name}-{$suffix}.jpg";
        if ( !imagejpeg( $newimage, $destfilename, apply_filters( 'jpeg_quality', $jpeg_quality, 'image_resize' ) ) )
            return new WP_Error('resize_path_invalid', __( 'Resize path invalid' ));
    }

    imagedestroy( $newimage );

    // Set correct file permissions
    $stat = stat( dirname( $destfilename ));
    $perms = $stat['mode'] & 0000666; //same permissions as parent folder, strip off the executable bits
    @ chmod( $destfilename, $perms );

    return $destfilename;
}

/**
 * Resize an image to make a thumbnail or intermediate size.
 *
 * The returned array has the file size, the image width, and image height. The
 * filter 'image_make_intermediate_size' can be used to hook in and change the
 * values of the returned array. The only parameter is the resized file path.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param string $file File path.
 * @param int $width Image width.
 * @param int $height Image height.
 * @param bool $crop Optional, default is false. Whether to crop image to specified height and width or resize.
 * @return bool|array False, if no image was created. Metadata array on success.
 */

I don't know how php works so I haven't tried anything.

It looks like the new server is running a later version of PHP than your old one, and the new one is being less forgiving about data types. We could give you a fix for this specific problem, but it's likely that you'll find other problems occurring, and ultimately you'll need to upgrade your WordPress site and all it's plugins to run with the new PHP version.

Looks like you've got WP_DEBUG enabled which displays warnings. You could turn that off which will hide the warning and probably produce a 0 for $perms. Be warned though, in PHP 8 this is now a fatal error

TBH I find this very strange for the mode returned by stat() to be non-numeric. That doesn't seem possible but... here we are ¯\(ツ)/¯
